# how can I mock a service to throw an exception a method that returns a List?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, jmock

I am facing this little issue. I have a service this way

```
public class Myservice {

   MyRestService myRestService; 

    public List<String> getNames() throws RestClientException {
        return myRestService.getNames();
    }

....
```

and a controller that is like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = URL, method = GET)
    public ModelAndView display(final ModelMap model) {
        ....
        try{
            List<String> listOfNames = myService.getNames();
        }catch(RestClientException e){
            LOG.error("Error when invoking Names service", e);
        }
        model.addAttribute("names", listOfNames);
        return new ModelAndView(VIEW, model);
    }....
```

So far works so good, the unit testing for the case the service actually
 returns a list of Strings works fine.

But since the service calls another one that is basically a rest client that could throw an exception, I want to mock that case.

If I have myService calling `myRestClientService` where `myRestClientService` throws an exception should I hadd to the method signature "throws Exception" ?

```
 final RestClientException myException =  mockery.mock(RestClientException.class);
        mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
            {
                oneOf(myService).getNames();
                will(returnValue(myException));
...
```

But I get an error that I cannot throw an exception from a method that only return List is there anyway to fix this? How could I test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation [Throwing Exceptions from Mocked Methods](http://www.jmock.org/throwing.html) you should use `throwException` rather than `returnValue`. It means code should be something like

```
 will(throwException(myException));
```

Answer (score 1):

It may not be necessary to mock **RestClientException**. The line could throw an IllegalArgumentException and stop there. E.g.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException is not an interface
```

A working **example** may look like the following:

```
@Test(expected = RestClientException.class)
public void testDisplayThrowException() throws Exception {
    MyService myService = mockery.mock(MyService.class);

    mockery.checking(new Expectations() {
        {
            allowing(myService).getNames();
            will(throwException(new RestClientException("Rest client is not working")));
        }
    });

    myService.getNames();
}
```